# Como colocar imágenes correctamente dentro de un ScrollView en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, android-imageview

Buenas tardes;

He intentado colocar varias imágenes dentro de un ScrollView, el problema que he tenido es que me genera un espacio arriba y abajo de la imagen; en este momento estoy agregando dos imágenes.

Cuando uso etiqueta de imagen de la siguiente manera me genera los espacios arriba y abajo de cada imagen:

```
           <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/calendario1" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/pregrado"/>
```

Aparentemente lo he corregido con el siguiente cambio: **android:layout_height="650dp"**

```
           <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="650dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendario1" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/pregrado"/>
```

Con este ancho y alto al emular me está mostrando las imágenes bien, pero, Con estas características ¿la imagen se muestra proporcionalmente en diferentes pantallas?, que es lo que no sé; ademas, me esta mostrando un Error:

**Reder problem**
[image: Error de imagen]

A continuación les relaciono el código completo de este layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.tecnologias.uniagustapp.fragmentos.Fragment_Calendario">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/calendario_acad_mico_i_2018"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#130f54"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="650dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendario1" android:contentDescription="@string/pregrado"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="650dp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendario2" android:contentDescription="@string/posgrado"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata cambiando la propiedad
adjustViewBounds a true en tu ImageView, ami me funciona para ajustar las imágenes a los contenedores.

Para que tus imagenes se adapten a los dispositivos normalmente dejo el ancho en match_parent y el alto en wrap_content, también he leído que para trabajar imágenes locales en Android es mejor que las utilices en formato .png
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo, he podido avanzar y con eso ya no no me muestra los espacios...